# Is it possible to integrate Spring MVC and a pre-existing web page?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, html

So, I have this Tomcat server. It's running some services which I'm using and I use it to support an existing application. Separately, I have a standalone webapp developed using javascript and HTML. It's in its own self-contained package-- a root folder with index.html and a bunch of subfolders containing the code. It's got a little interactive part after which I need to store data from it.

I want to host the webpage on my Tomcat server and then use spring MVC to build a simple web service to deal with receiving and persisting the data gained from the interactive part.

I've taken a look at few other questions, but none have seemed to be what I'm looking for. Specifically, [Is a parallel Spring-MVC application possible with a non-spring web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052542/is-a-parallel-spring-mvc-application-possible-with-a-non-spring-web-app) talks in general about using another thing (where I just want to literally serve that one HTML file) and everything I've read about how to set up Spring MVC starts talking about serving .jsp pages, which I don't have and don't want. One of the answers on [How to access static resources when mapping a global front controller servlet on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/) gets close to what I'm looking for, but instead of displaying an index.html it reroutes that file to a servlet, which is (I think?) exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Any advice for things to look into, or am I on a wild goose chase with this one?

Comment: Just to clarify, do the "services that you're using" or the "supported existing application" have anything to do with the self-contained JS/HTML application or that's just providing some context on your setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just create simple Java servlet project and map Spring dispatcher servlet to other url than root. Then your 'interactive part' might be at webapp root, which will be served by tomcat as a static content starting from url:

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/
```

and spring webservice will be mapped to url:

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/other_than_root/
```

You can configure servlet's mapping in web.xml:

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/other_than_root/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Starting with 3.0.4 (I think), Spring MVC allows you to define an `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` in order to allow mapping the dispatcher servlet on `/` and still let the container serve the static resources.

Comment: You are right Costi, `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` will work to, but going this way I would rather use '<mvc:resources>'. IMHO instead of nesting static webapp inside Spring MVC, separating them by different mappings using servlet specyfication methods is cleaner and simpler.